# Mockito: "Wanted but not invoked: [...] Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock."

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have gone through posts on StackOverflow.

> Wanted but not invoked: Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

I did do what was asked there still I am missing something. Can you please help me what I am missing?

My Java code:

```
public class AccountController {

    public ResponseEntity<AccountResponse> getAccountByAccountId(
            @RequestHeader("Authorization") final String accountToken,
            @PathVariable("accountId") String accountId) {

        return accountHandler.apply(() -> {

            final AcccountResponse accountResponse = accountService
                    .getAccountByAccountId(accountId);

            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(accountResponse);

        });
    }
}
```

My unit test:

```
@InjectMocks
private AccountController accountController;

@Mock
private AccountService accountService;

@Mock
private AccountHandler accountHandler;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Supplier<ResponseEntity<AccountResponse>>> responseAccount;

private static AccountResponse accountResponse;

@Before
public void setUp() {

    responseEntity = ResponseEntity.ok().body(accountResponse);
}

@Test
public void getAccountByAccountIdTest() {

    when(accountHandler.apply(responseAccount.capture())).thenReturn(responseEntity);
    when(accountService.getAccountByAccountId(accountId)).thenReturn(accountResponse);

    ResponseEntity<AccountResponse> accountResult = accountController.getAccountByAccountId(accountToken, accountId);

    assertNotNull(accountResult);
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, accountResult.getStatusCode());
    assertSame(accountResponse, accountResult.getBody());
    verify(accountHandler).apply(responseAccount.capture());
    verify(accountService).getAccountByAccountId(accountId); // this fails and gives me error
}
```

Everything works fine except `verify(acccountService).getAccountByAccountId(accountId);`
I get error as

```
Wanted but not invoked:
acccountService.getAccountByAccountId(

    "accountId"
);
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `accountHandler` is a mock, which means that `apply` will do only what you stub it to do.  When you stubbed it, you didn't make it call the `Supplier<ResponseEntity<AccountResponse>>` that was passed to it, which is why `getAccountByAccountId` never got called.

Probably the easiest way to make this work is to use a real `AccountHandler` instead of a mock, for your `accountHandler` field.

An alternative would be to use a Mockito `Answer` to make the `apply` method work.